# Bash regexp in if statement doesn't work

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to play with regular expressions in bash but i can't understand why this follow scenario doesn't work :

Regexp:

```
REGEXP="^(test\/)(([a-zA-Z]+)\-)+(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)$"
```

String:

```
STRING="test/test-ods-1.10.1"
```

Test:

```
if [[ "$STRING" =~ $REGEXP ]]
then
       echo "match!"
else
       echo "don't match"
fi
```

Normally in this scenario I should receive a "match" but it's always returning a "doesn't match".

Comment: Just a small hint `[[ "foo" =~ foo ]]; echo $?` shows 0 in case of a match, 1 if not, and 2 if there is a syntax error in the regex.

Answer (score 3):

`\d` is not defined in bash regexps. Replace them with `[0-9]` and it'll work :

```
$ [[ "test/test-1.10.1" =~ ^(test\/)(([a-zA-Z]+)\-)+(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)$ ]]; echo $?
1

$ [[ "test/test-1.10.1" =~ ^(test\/)(([a-zA-Z]+)\-)+(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)\.(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$ ]]; echo $?
0
```

No shorthand classes are defined in POSIX, and GNU extensions only bring a few of them, `\w`, `\W`, `\s` and `\S` according to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html).